# How to extend the functionality of the functools.wraps decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, functools

I'd like to create a new decorator to use in place of `@wraps(f)` that does whatever magic `@wraps(f)` would do as well as something else. How would I do that?

Specifically, I've got several decorators that are of the form:

```
def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # does some stuff in here
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    if not hasattr(wrapper, '_first_line'):
        wrapper._first_line = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[1]
    return wrapper
```

It seems like I should be able to create a decorator like `@wraps_with_first_line(f)` which will do all that `@wraps(f)` is doing as well as `if not hasattr(wrapper, '_first_line'): wrapper._first_line = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to add *isn't* already an attribute of the wrapped object, then you can use this:

```
def wraps_with_first_line(f):
    def wrap(wrapper):
        wrapper = wraps(f)(wrapper)
        if not hasattr(wrapper, '_first_line'):
            wrapper._first_line = inspect.getsourcelines(f)[1] 
        return wrapper
    return wrap
```

If it *is* already an attribute of the wrapped object, use Sven's method.

Comment: I ended up using a mix of your answer and Sven's, but it felt more like yours.

Answer (score 3):

You should rather follow the good practice of adding a `__wrapped__` attribute pointing to the wrapped function than adding single attributes of that wrapped function.  [New versions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) of `functools.wraps()` do this automatically, but if you are using an older version of Python than 3.2, you can als easily extend `wraps()` to add `__wrapped__`:

```
def my_wraps(wrapped, **kwargs):
    def decorator(wrapper):
        functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, wrapped, **kwargs)
        wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped
    return decorator
```

**Edit**:  Here's a function the extracts the original function from a possibly multiply decorated function:

```
def orig_function(f):
    try:
        while True:
            f = f.__wrapped__
    except AttributeError:
        return f
```

Comment: In my particular use case, I have some functions that are decorated/wrapped more than once—in those cases, looking at `some_func.__wrapped__` would point me at the intermediate wrapper, right?  Could I safely do something like the `if not hasattr...` in my original code to set `_original_wrapped` or some such?  (Is this effectively what's done in [agf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10032158/291280)?)

Comment: @Isaac:  You could also write a utility function that extracts the original function by following the chain of `__wrapped__` arguments.  Of course you can do inside `decorator()` above whatever you want.